# SPARQL query to extract value of dbpedia page

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a URL of a person http://dbpedia.org/page/John_Terry
And I'm trying to extract value of his name, position, club and date of birth.
Ideally the output would be:

### Name | Position | DOB | Club

John Terry | Defender | 1980-12-07 | Chelsea

Here is my attempt of the query after some digging:

`SELECT ?name ?pos ?birthDate  ? where { 
  ?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:John_Terry .
  ?x dbpedia-owl:name ?name .
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate .
  ?x dbpedia-owl:position ?pos .
  ?x dbpedia-owl:currentClub ?club
}`

Which I understand is not the ideal way of doing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Why the `owl:sameAs` triple pattern to a totally different resource `dbpedia:Anthony_Martial`? same as would mean that both resources are the same, doesn't make sense here, right?

Comment: Moreover, your query has some error, e.g. the `?` in the SELECT part, I guess it should be `?club`. And although `owl:sameAs?` is a valid property path since SPARQL 1.1 , I'm pretty sure that this is also not what you wanted to write, i.e. the `?` here is wrong.

Comment: Yea, the owl:sameAs was from another post that produced similar result. I didn't really understand what it meant.

Comment: `owl:sameAs` is a predefined property in the OWL vocabulary and has a fixed semantics stating that both denote the same entity.

Answer (score 1):

Why the `owl:sameAs` triple pattern to a totally different resource `dbpedia:Anthony_Martial`? same as would mean that both resources `dbpedia:Anthony_Martial` and `dbpedia:John_Terry` are the same, doesn't make sense here, right?

You have the resource `dbpedia:John_Terry` for which you want to have the information, i.e. that is your `?x`.

More comments:
* there is no property `dbpedia-owl: name`, you could use `foaf:name`.
* there is no property `dbpedia-owl:currentClub`. `dbpedia-owl` is a (deprecated) prefix for `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, but the correct namespace for `currentClub` would be `http://dbpedia.org/property/` 
and its written `current`**c**`lub`, no camel-case here

A possible solution:

```sql
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?name ?pos ?birthDate  ?club WHERE { 
  dbpedia:John_Terry foaf:name ?name ;
                     dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
                     dbo:position ?pos ;
                     dbp:currentclub ?club

}
```

returns

```
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
|          name          |                             pos                             | birthDate  |                   club                   |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| "John George Terry"@en | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Defender_(association_football) | 1980-12-07 | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chelsea_F.C. |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
```